# Como saber o link da chamada View() .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um *controller* com uma *view* no final para mostrar detalhes de uma empresa. Estou a fazer um código que permita gerar um url para os detalhes da empresa através do **goo.gl** para ser mais fácil e agradável partilhar, e preciso de colocar como parâmetro de entrada o link para a *view*. Esse link fica guardado na base de dados, associado ao meu modelo. Veja:

```
public ActionResult scoreDetails(int id)
{        
    res = PresentationServices.Helper.GetCompanyDetails(id);                
    //ShortLink 
    ViewBag.shortLink = 
    PresentationServices.Helper.GetCompanyShortLink(id, "LINK PARA A VIEW" );
    return View(res);
}
```

Comment: Pra que `cast` de `int` em uma variável que é `int` `(int)id`????

Comment: para nada kkk, obrigado pelo reparo já tirei do meu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais simples de obter isso é através do [`Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ViewBag.shortLink = 
    PresentationServices.Helper.GetCompanyShortLink((int)id, Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery);
```